# CSS substitute to $.show();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a popup that shows up really nicely with this jQuery method:

```
$("#pop").show(450);
```

What is an appropriate css substitute that will do an identical job (with the 450ms time)?
Is there really a performance difference in favor of css? If so, Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this. The idea is you put the popup in the back with and make the opacity 0. Then when it has the class, "show" it brings it to the front and makes it fully visible.

```
#pop{
    -webkit-transition: ease opacity 450ms
    -moz-transition: ease opacity 450ms
    transition: ease opacity 450ms
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#pop.show{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I enable the new #pop.show? Something like this? $( "p" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );

Comment: yes, you'd just add the class using whatever method you deem appropriate.

Comment: for some reason that does not seem to work for me. my css is: #pop {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            z-index: 10;
            opacity: 0;
            } and when I had "poppy" which is opacity:1 nothing happens.         $('#pop').addClass('poppy');

Answer (score 1):

The show/hide methods work by changing the inline style of the element's opacity from 0-1 or vise versa.  As such you can make some css styles that perform the same animation.

The thought behind css being better at this than javascript is because javascript will do this by changing the DOM frequently, resulting in many recalculations of the elements, not just the one you are changing potentially.

When you do this with CSS, not only does the browser have the chance to optimize with using the GPU to do this, but the GPU can animate things like opacity at a very low cost since it knows that doing so will have limited affect on other elements.

EDIT: Others may correct me, but this is what I have gathered from my own research on the matter.
One reference article: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Answer (score 1):

> Using keyframes, animation-fill, animation-delay, animation-duration,
>   opaticy way in **CSS3**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300);

body {padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: #333;}

.container {position: fixed; top: 25%; left: 25%;}

/* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
  opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
  -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;
}

.fade-in.one {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.fade-in.two {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.fade-in.three {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.6s;
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}

/*---make a basic box ---*/
#pop{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #999;
}
#pop1{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #999;
}
#pop2{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="pop" class="box fade-in one">
    look at me fade in
  </div>

  <div id="pop1" class="box fade-in two">
    Oh hi! i can fade too!
  </div>

  <div id="pop2" class="box fade-in three">
   Oh hi! i can fade three!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no need for this in such a basic case. Take a look at the answer of @Chase W.